# How can I build and run a C++ file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation

I'm new to Visual Studio Code, I've been trying to run a "Hello World" program but it's not working and I get this message:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Israa\Desktop\wow.cpp\.vscode\" && g++ hello.cpp -o hello && "c:\Users\Israa\Desktop\wow.cpp\.vscode\"hello
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.044 seconds
```

I think it's something related to the path somehow, I manually installed the minGW. Can someone tell me what is wrong?
[image: here is a pic of the error]

Comment: _"I think it's something related to the path somehow, i manually installed the minGW"_ Be more specific. Give details. Tell us _exactly_ what you did. We can otherwise only guess and that just wastes everybody's time, including yours!

Comment: Make sure the bin folder in the MinGW installation is in your system path. There are several examples of how to do this already on Stack Overflow if you have missed this step.

Comment: I would guess, with the '&&' that you are combining 3 commands on one line.  Have you tried one command at a time?  Does the g++ command fail by itself?  Does your system have a search tool to report where your g++ is installed?  (On Linux, I use 'locate'.)  Do you agree that the g++ command was not found?  So the "hello' app did not build?